# How to get Tokens in account by Pubkey of account owner using RPC API

Tags: jsonrpc-api

I tried getTokenAccountsByOwner but that requires a mint or programId which I don't have. What if I want to figure out which tokens an account has such as NFTs using only the Pubkey of account owner?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to use the programID of the token program -

> {
> 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
> 'id': 1,
> 'method': 'getTokenAccountsByOwner',
> 'params': [
> ,
> {
> 'programId': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'
> },
> {
> 'encoding': 'jsonParsed'
> }
> ]
> }